# How do I fix doorbell buttons ring but do not light?

Tags: wiring, doorbell

I had a lighted front (ding dong) and back (ding) doorbell that were both working. When the front button stopped ringing but was lit and the back button rang but stopped lighting, I replaced both buttons, then the chime, and finally the transformer. Both front and back doorbells now ring as spec'd but neither is lit. I have reversed wires on both buttons but both remain unlit. Don't know what else to try. The original installation used 22 gauge wire, but both buttons were lit and rang for a decade with no problem until recently. Suggestions? Rewiring with heavier gauge wire is not an option.

Comment: what kind of buttons did you install?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Perhaps you installed non lighted buttons.  Not all are manufactured with a light.

Comment: I installed a new Emtek button and new Craftmade button -- both identical to what had been installed before. Both are lit buttons and were working for a few years with no problems. Then the Emtek button was lit but did not ring; the Craftmade button rang but was no longer lit. That was when I replaced both buttons. The Craftmade button lit and rang for a few minutes, then failed. That is when I replaced the chime (with same as previous model: Utilitech). When neither button lit (but both rang correctly), I replaced the transformer. Still both buttons ring correctly but Problem: do not light.

Comment: "The Craftmade button lit and rang for a few minutes, then failed." so you started replacing _other_ components? Why not replace the component that worked briefly but failed? Seems to me that at least part of the problem is this button.

Comment: The Craftmade button that lit and rang for a few minutes was a new identical button for one that had stopped lighting but rang.

Answer (score 2):

You have too many unknowns to figure this out with logic.  The first question is whether your components are working and able to work together as you desire; the second is whether the wiring supports your circuit needs.  To determine whether your components are working and able to work together for your purpose:

1. Uninstall all the parts and lay them out on your workbench.
2. Wire them together per your plan.
3. Power up and see if everything works.
4. If it works, label the wires and connections, draw a diagram, and take a picture.  If it doesn't, replace the defective components.
5. Then install it with the house doorbell wiring.  If it works, congrats! If it doesn't, you have to troubleshoot the wiring.  Edit your question to reflect what you've done, and include the diagram and pix.